# What determines the default version of .NET Framwork in visual studio 2019?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

When I create a new project using VS 2019, .NET Framework version 4.7.2 is selected by default, although 4.8 is available. Why would the default not be the latest version?

I feel like this must have been asked before, but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: 4.8 was not yet available when VS2019 was released, 4.7.2 was current back in April 2019.  Otherwise it is simply the version you used in your previous project.  Don't sweat it.

Comment: Thanks, it was more a curiosity than anything else. :)